# swift 3 - Como persistir objetos

Tags: ios, swift, swift-3

Sou desenvolvedor Android e estou tentando aprender algumas coisas para iOS também.
Tenho me batido um pouco em coisas simples, como salvar persistir um objeto meu para pegar ele novamente outra hora. No Android eu usaria um `SharedPreference` e resolveria tudo.

No Swift 3 eu não estou sabendo como fazer isso. Já vi que o `NSUserDefaults` não salva objetos.

Posteriormente tentei utilizar o `NSCoding`, que ficou assim:

```
class Appointment: NSObject, NSCoding {
let custoMercadoria: Double
let custoServico: Double
let aliquotaSimples: Double
let margem: Double
let fretePreco: Double
let cobrancaPreco: Double
let otherCost: Double

override init(){
 }

init(Appointment : (Double,Double,Double,Double,Double,Double,Double)){
    self.custoMercadoria = Appointment.0
    self.custoServico = Appointment.1
    self.aliquotaSimples = Appointment.2
    self.margem = Appointment.3
    self.fretePreco = Appointment.4
    self.cobrancaPreco = Appointment.5
    self.otherCost = Appointment.6
}
    func getAppointment() -> (Double,Double,Double,Double,Double,Double,Double) {
        return (self.custoMercadoria,self.custoServico,self.aliquotaSimples,self.margem,self.fretePreco,self.cobrancaPreco,self.otherCost)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.custoMercadoria = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey:"custoMercadoria") as! Double
        self.custoServico = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "custoServico") as! Double
        self.aliquotaSimples = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "aliquotaSimples") as! Double
        self.margem = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "margem") as! Double
        self.fretePreco = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "fretePreco") as! Double
        self.cobrancaPreco = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "cobrancaPreco") as! Double
        self.otherCost = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "otherCost") as! Double

    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder){
        aCoder.encode(self.custoMercadoria, forKey: "custoMercadoria")
        aCoder.encode(self.custoServico, forKey: "custoServico")
        aCoder.encode(self.aliquotaSimples, forKey: "aliquotaSimples")
        aCoder.encode(self.margem, forKey: "margem")
        aCoder.encode(self.fretePreco, forKey: "fretePreco")
        aCoder.encode(self.cobrancaPreco, forKey: "cobrancaPreco")
        aCoder.encode(self.otherCost, forKey: "otherCost")
    }
}
```

Estou em duvida se a montagem da classe está correta, inicializando os atributos, encode e decode. Se alguém tiver algum exemplo de como utilizar também agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira de resolver utilizando Swift em uma versão mais atual é  através do "protocolo" Codable. (protocolo aqui entre aspas porque é o nome que se dá a uma interface [fazendo uma analogia conceitual com outras linguagens de programação] na linguagem de programação Swift)

Para conseguir gravar os dados vai precisar mudar um pouco a sua estrutura atual, (vamos ter que trocar a `classe (class)` por uma `struct` basta adicionar o protocolo `Codable` à sua struct, a linguagem Swift já possui suporte a armazenar os dados automaticamente para atributos de tipos primitivos.

Desta forma, basta adaptar o seu código:

```
import Foundation
struct Appointment: Codable {
    let custoMercadoria: Double
    let custoServico: Double
    let aliquotaSimples: Double
    let margem: Double
    let fretePreco: Double
    let cobrancaPreco: Double
    let otherCost: Double
}
```

Segue a documentação do protocolo [Codable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable)

Depois crie uma classe que vai manipular e possui a responsabilidade de apresentar e notificar mudanças nos dados em sua view/viewcontroller.

Para esta finalidade basta declarar uma classe variável que possui o tipo de sua classe, e implementar o método `didSet` para esta varíável, assim como o método init(), isso pode ser feito da seguinte forma:

```
import Foundation

class AppointmentHolder: ObservableObject {
    @Published var appointment : Appointment {
        didSet {
            if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(appointment) {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "appointment")
            }
        }
    }
    init() {
        if let savedData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "appointment") {
                if let decodedItems = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Appointment.self, from: savedData) {
                    appointment = decodedItems
                    return
                }
            }
        //executado caso não encontre nenhum dado da aplicação salvo com a chave "appointment" salvo no sistema de arquivos e que foi buscado via o método  `UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "appointment")`
        appointment = Appointment(custoMercadoria: 0.0, custoServico: 0.0, aliquotaSimples: 0.0, margem: 0.0, fretePreco: 0.0, cobrancaPreco: 0.0, otherCost: 0.0)
    }
}
```

Após essas implementações poderá rastrear mudanças em seu objeto através de uma view, da seguinte forma:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var conf: AppointmentHolder
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack {
                Text(conf.appointment.custoMercadoria, format: .number)
                Text(conf.appointment.custoServico, format: .number)
                Text(conf.appointment.aliquotaSimples, format: .number)
                Text(conf.appointment.cobrancaPreco,  format: .number)
                // resto do objeto
                }
            .navigationTitle("Exemplo")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(conf: AppointmentHolder())
    }
}
```

Em resumo seria isso.

Tudo que foi implementado utiliza bibliotecas padrão da linguagem Swift, não é necessário instalar nenhuma biblioteca externa (de terceiros).

---

Uma coisa que vale a pena ressaltar é que criou um objeto imutável, pois declarou todos os atributos com o modificador `let` nos atributos da struct. Neste caso para criar um objeto mutável basta trocar o modificador `let` para o tipo `var`.

Answer (score -3):

Você pode utilizar o Realm para persistir esses dados no banco de dados, é simples e fácil de utilizar.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/112544/realm-tutorial-getting-started

Depois para serializar e deserializar esse objeto você pode usar o https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Comment: Nao consigo fazer isso de uma meneira mais simples? Acho que é pouco dado pra utilizar um BD, nesse caso

Comment: @LuanGabriel depende do que você for salvar, o NSUserDefaults não foi feito para você salvar objetos inteiros...

Answer (score -3):

Para guardar coisas na memória do dispositivo eu acho o CoreData ótimo. Você consegue modelar direitinhos os objetos que precisa guardar, definir relacionamentos e é relativamente fácil de buscar e registrar objetos...

Answer (score -3):

Tens várias maneiras de persistir dados em IOS.

Tens o `UserDefaults` mas que o objetivo não é guardar grandes quantidades de dados. Só podes guardar dados primitivos.

Tens SQLLite ou wrappers para o mesmo como FMDB e CordeData (Apple)

E tens a minha favorita. Realm. Muito bom, já traz mecanismos como triggers que dão muito jeito.